# Want to know the best option to use for a database of this sort of android application

Tags: android, mysql, mysql-workbench

This is for an app for a  clinic giving course in stop smoking and nicotine addiction,

We want to make sample app for android, where we scheduled the treatments course time plan, that’ remind the patients when to take the medicine.
So when the patient start their treatment, they just register at the day of starting the treatment, then automatically the app will scheduled all the following treatment, and send a reminder when next treatment arrive.

I know this topic is broad to answer but I just want to know how to make the database (schedules of the prescription) set for the timer to activate?? Can I use an external database that is network based..If so how to do that???Is sqlite a better option??? And how to automatically get those data and schedule it in the android app??

Comment: You are right, this is too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the data will be shown to all users like the time table so they can reserve if there is an empty date, then you require to have a cloud database and i suggest you to start learning how to connect android with MySQL here is a great [video tutorial](http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/12924/android-tutorial-using-remote-databases-php-and-mysql-part-1/) of how to connect android with MySQL by the help of PHP and JSON.

Now if you want this application to work offline, you require to have a SQLite database that when you connect to the internet once, you save these data in it. and whenever the device connects to the internet it updates the database entries.

for alerting the paitents you will have a service that runs to check the data , then start a notification. It may be possible to have an event listener for some given event that would start your service that would then check the date, and if so post your notification!

here is a good [tutoial](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/notification-for-a-user-chosen-time/) about it.

I hope I have covered most of your questions. There may be a better solutions around so dig more. Good luck with your app.